# Admob - no test ad fill from ad server after stress testing with monkey

Tags: android, admob, stress-testing, monkey

I was testing my android app using monkey and there might have been thousands of successive ad-requests while the test was on. The test went fine.

Now, I no more get any fill for test ads.

Logcat reads:

> No fill from ad sever.
>
> Failed to load ad: 3

Neither my app nor the ad id is suspended. Ads are working good on all non-test devices (this is not a duplicate question).

I tried changing the android id of my test device and ads appeared. But as soon as I added the (hash of) new device id to test devices, the problem returned.

So, I concluded that test ads have been somehow disabled for my app. How do I enable the test ads again and how do I prevent this from happening in future while stress testing with monkey.

I have also sent an email to admob support regarding the issue and await their response.

Any information or help will be highly appreciated.

EDIT

It was a problem at admob's end and they have fixed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue, I didn't run any stress test just usual development/debugging. It looks like AdMob problem, lets wait day or two...
Hopefully someone from AdMob will fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Been struggling with this problem since hours, now I can relax.